# Tax situation for telecommuting (remote work)

Tags: united-states, taxes, form-w-4

I am a non-resident alien. I am in a similar situation as described here - [How to determine the tax withhold for remote work?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/125443/how-to-determine-the-tax-withhold-for-remote-work) To quickly summarize, my official address of residence is in state A, I am temporarily working remotely from state B, and my company is located in state C.

My company has asked me to fill out the [W-4 form](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf). What address should be entered in the W-4 form for federal taxes? My company is aware that I'm working remotely from state B. However, I think that the correct address to be entered would be that of state A?

Comment: The address on the Federal W-4 doesn't make much difference. Your question should be which state version of the w-4 should you fill out. Your address on the federal W-4 is where you live, not where you work.

Comment: I figured out the part about state taxes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address of the Federal W-4 is the address that payroll will be using if they send a paper copy of your W-2. It plays no other role in the tax system.

The companies I have worked for send a reminder email to make sure the address information on the W-2 is correct or the paper copy of the W-2 might not get there. Many years ago this message was added as a note on a late in the year pay stub.

Of course some companies only distribute the W-2 electronically or in the case of a small business they may distribute it at the place of work. Delivering it in person might not work for a company with remote workers or multiple locations.

I have no idea which address will be used if the state and federal W-4 disagree.